# How to install Highly Available Vault Cluster with Integrated Storage (Raft) on the kubernetes?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

This is the article I refer to.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/helm/examples/ha-with-raft

```
root@Will-T-PC:~# helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.1", GitCommit:"293b50c65d4d56187cd4e2f390f0ada46b4c4737", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.10"}
```

[image]

After I refer to this to implement, I get an error.

```
$ kubectl describe pod  vault-0  -n vault
```

Error:
Readiness probe failed: Error checking seal status: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

```
        root@Will-T-PC:~/.kube# helm install vault hashicorp/vault \
         --names>     --namespace vault \
         --set ">     --set "server.ha.enabled=true" \
        --set ">     --set "server.ha.replicas=3"
        
        NAME: vault
        LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Apr 27 21:45:46 2023
        NAMESPACE: vault
        STATUS: deployed
        REVISION: 1
        NOTES:
        Thank you for installing HashiCorp Vault!
        
        Now that you have deployed Vault, you should look over the docs on using
        Vault with Kubernetes available here:
        
        https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
        
        
        Your release is named vault. To learn more about the release, try:
        
          $ helm status vault
          $ helm get manifest vault
        
        
        root@Will-T-PC:~/.kube#
        root@Will-T-PC:~/.kube# kubectl get all -n vault
        NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
        pod/vault-0                                 0/1     Running   0          2m43s
        pod/vault-1                                 0/1     Running   0          2m43s
        pod/vault-2                                 0/1     Pending   0          2m43s
        pod/vault-agent-injector-84bb6bcd84-swbmr   1/1     Running   0          2m44s
        
        NAME                               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
        service/vault                      ClusterIP   10.100.58.87     <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   2m45s
        service/vault-active               ClusterIP   10.100.166.159   <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   2m45s
        service/vault-agent-injector-svc   ClusterIP   10.100.169.60    <none>        443/TCP             2m45s
        service/vault-internal             ClusterIP   None             <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   2m45s
        service/vault-standby              ClusterIP   10.100.185.43    <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   2m45s
        
        NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
        deployment.apps/vault-agent-injector   1/1     1            1           2m46s
        
        NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
        replicaset.apps/vault-agent-injector-84bb6bcd84   1         1         1       2m47s
        
        NAME                     READY   AGE
        statefulset.apps/vault   0/3     2m46s
        
        
        root@Will-T-PC:~/.kube# kubectl exec -ti vault-0 -- vault operator init
        Error from server (NotFound): pods "vault-0" not found
        
        
        
        root@Will-T-PC:~# kubectl describe pod vault-0 -n vault
        Name:             vault-0
        Namespace:        vault
        Priority:         0
        Service Account:  vault
        Node:             ip-172-16-2-86.us-west-1.compute.internal/172.16.2.86
        Start Time:       Thu, 27 Apr 2023 21:46:04 +0800
        Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=vault
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=vault
                          component=server
                          controller-revision-hash=vault-767b9b789b
                          helm.sh/chart=vault-0.24.0
                          statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=vault-0
        Annotations:      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
        Status:           Running
        IP:               172.16.11.137
        IPs:
          IP:           172.16.11.137
        Controlled By:  StatefulSet/vault
        Containers:
          vault:
            Container ID:  docker://4b04532f40a5465b803e8ef780c163f6836e5ee808907140e3af428eb4ec35fb
            Image:         hashicorp/vault:1.13.1
            Image ID:      docker-pullable://hashicorp/vault@sha256:b888abc3fc0529550d4a6c87884419e86b8cb736fe556e3e717a6bc50888b3b8
            Ports:         8200/TCP, 8201/TCP, 8202/TCP
            Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
            Command:
              /bin/sh
              -ec
            Args:
              cp /vault/config/extraconfig-from-values.hcl /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${HOST_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOST_IP|${HOST_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${POD_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|POD_IP|${POD_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${HOSTNAME}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOSTNAME|${HOSTNAME?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${API_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|API_ADDR|${API_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${TRANSIT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|TRANSIT_ADDR|${TRANSIT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              [ -n "${RAFT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|RAFT_ADDR|${RAFT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
              /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh vault server -config=/tmp/storageconfig.hcl
        
            State:          Running
              Started:      Thu, 27 Apr 2023 21:46:10 +0800
            Ready:          False
            Restart Count:  0
            Readiness:      exec [/bin/sh -ec vault status -tls-skip-verify] delay=5s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=2    Environment:
              HOST_IP:               (v1:status.hostIP)
              POD_IP:                (v1:status.podIP)
              VAULT_K8S_POD_NAME:   vault-0 (v1:metadata.name)
              VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE:  vault (v1:metadata.namespace)
              VAULT_ADDR:           http://127.0.0.1:8200
              VAULT_API_ADDR:       http://$(POD_IP):8200
              SKIP_CHOWN:           true
              SKIP_SETCAP:          true
              HOSTNAME:             vault-0 (v1:metadata.name)
              VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR:   https://$(HOSTNAME).vault-internal:8201
              HOME:                 /home/vault
            Mounts:
              /home/vault from home (rw)
              /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-92p4n (ro)
              /vault/config from config (rw)
        Conditions:
          Type              Status
          Initialized       True
          Ready             False
          ContainersReady   False
          PodScheduled      True
        Volumes:
          config:
            Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
            Name:      vault-config
            Optional:  false
          home:
            Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
            Medium:
            SizeLimit:  <unset>
          kube-api-access-92p4n:
            Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
            TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
            ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
            ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
            DownwardAPI:             true
        QoS Class:                   BestEffort
        Node-Selectors:              <none>
        Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                                     node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
        Events:
          Type     Reason       Age                    From               Message
          ----     ------       ----                   ----               -------
          Normal   Scheduled    4m44s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned vault/vault-0 to ip-172-16-2-86.us-west-1.compute.internal
          Warning  FailedMount  4m43s                  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
          Normal   Pulling      4m42s                  kubelet            Pulling image "hashicorp/vault:1.13.1"
          Normal   Pulled       4m39s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "hashicorp/vault:1.13.1" in 3.351737534s (3.351743554s including waiting)
          Normal   Created      4m38s                  kubelet            Created container vault
          Normal   Started      4m38s                  kubelet            Started container vault
          **Warning  Unhealthy    3m2s (x20 over 4m32s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Error checking seal status: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused**
        root@Will-T-PC:~#
```

```
root@Will-T-PC:~# kubectl exec -it  vault-0  -n vault
error: you must specify at least one command for the container
root@Will-T-PC:~#
root@Will-T-PC:~# kubectl exec -it  vault-0  -n vault -- vault status
Error checking seal status: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
command terminated with exit code 1
```

```
root@Will-T-PC:~# kubectl exec -it  vault-0  -n vault -- vault operator init
Get "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
command terminated with exit code 2
```

[image]
It looks like the container didn't start successfully and I don't know what steps I'm missing.

```
Thanks!
```

Comment: You'll need to run the `vault operator init` command before Vault can start up; in your output, it looks like you forgot to specify the namespace when running that line which I think is why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I just updated the description of the problem. A screenshot of this command is attached. It still gives an error.

Comment: You may need to check the logs for the vault-0 pod to see what error message is happening under hood... I know it's tough when the containers keep exiting. I find the k9s tool makes it a little easier to do.

Comment: this is a bit broad question, you might need to check and go step by step. and as i see you dont have the vault in a ready state yet, and hence you might want to debug further from the logs etc why is it so! and the question is completely unrelated,